# Label Heights In Binary Tree Efficiently

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to figure out how to label each node in a binary tree with its height.  I can do this inefficiently as follows:

```
def getHeight(node)
    if node is None:
        return 0
    return 1 + max(node.left, node.right)

def labelHeights(root):
    if root is None:
        return
    root.height = getHeight(root)
    labelHeights(root.left)
    labelHeights(root.right)
```

However, this wastes a lot of time and is O(n^2) in the number of nodes in the binary tree.

I think I want to work "bottom-up": calculating the height of a node's children (if not already stored) and using that to set the height of the node in question.

I'm a bit stumped.

FYI, this isn't a HW problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `getHeight`.  You can do this depth-first in O(N) by just having `labelHeights` return the height of each subtree.  e.g.

```
def labelHeights(n):
    if n is None:
        return 0
    lh = labelHeights(n.left)
    rh = labelHeights(n.right)
    n.height = max(lh, rh) + 1
    return n.height
```

Answer (score 0):

Python is not my primary language so don't judge on code style.

Given this class:

```
class Node:
def __init__(self, key):
    self.data = key
    self.left = None
    self.right = None
    self.label = 0
```

You can make a `level order traversal`  using a `queue`.

```
def levelOrder(root):
levelLabel = 0
if root is None:
    return
queue = []
queue.append(root)

tempQueue = []

while (len(queue) > 0 or len(tempQueue) > 0):
    node = queue.pop(0)
    node.label = levelLabel
    print node.data , " " , node.label
    if node.left is not None:
        tempQueue.append(node.left)

    if node.right is not None:
        tempQueue.append(node.right)

    if(len(queue) == 0):
        levelLabel += 1
        queue = tempQueue
        tempQueue = []
```

In `tempQueue` will be stored all the nodes at a certain level.

If `len(queue) == 0` is true, it means a level is traversed so we increment the `levelLabel` variable.

Example of usage :

```
root = Node(1)
root.left = Node(2)
root.right = Node(3)
root.left.left = Node(4)
root.left.right = Node(5)
root.left.right.right = Node(6)
root.left.right.left = Node(7)
root.left.right.right.left = Node(8)
```

Result:

```
1  - level  0
2  - level  1
3  - level  1
4  - level  2
5  - level  2
7  - level  3
6  - level  3
8  - level  4
```

The complexity of this algorithm is `O(n)`.